# Unity 2019 - SDK tools version 0.0 < 26.1.1

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk

I have Unity 2019.3.13 and I want to build android apps. I have Android Studio already installed with the SDK. I have the JDK path and the SDK setted in Unity preferences but when I try to build I got this error: "SDK tools version 0.0 < 26.1.1"

Answer (score 0):

Open the Unity hub,  from the installs tab and for the version you are using: **...>** After clicking **Add Modules**, you need to select> **Android build support>** Make sure that **Android SDK & NDK** is selected and click Next. If downloads fail, unselect **MS Visual** from **Add modules** and try.
After the downloads are finished, **Unity> Preferences> External Tools>** leave the check mark of **Android SDK and NDK** (Unity will choose it) and save it. You can now build without problems.